# query no obtienes datos a través de php

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo un sistema `php`, que muestra información de facturas autorizadas de cada usuario logueado en sistema.

La query que trae los datos, al ejecutarla en `sqlserver` trae los datos de forma exitosa (para todos los usuarios del sistema).
pero al ejecutarla a través de `php` no me trae los datos (para algunos usuarios).

Pienso que puede ser un problema del código de la aplicación.
pero no lo veo tan así,

El motivo es debido a que cuando me logueo con `usuario1`,
este me muestra los datos a través de `sqlserver` y también a través de la aplicación `php`,
Pero cuando me logueo con `usuario 2`, este solo me trae datos en `sqlserver`, pero no los trae a través de la aplicación `php`.

Es un poco raro, esto me comenzó a pasar hace un tiempo, debido a que antes no sucedía.

Esta es la query:

```
SELECT
f.idFactura,
CONVERT(CHAR(10), f.fecha_recepcion, 103) AS fecha_recepcion,
f.numero_documento,
CONVERT(CHAR(10), f.fecha_emision, 103) AS fecha_emision,
f.rut_proveedor,
f.razon_social,
f.monto_bruto,
f.indicador_moneda,
f.valor_indicador,
df.idDocumentoFactura,
df.nombre AS nombre_digital,
rd.idRegistroDocumento,
(
SELECT
em.nombre
FROM [Informatica].[Sistemas].[Empresa] AS em
WHERE em.codigo = f.codigo_empresa
AND em.habilitado = 1
)AS nombre_empresa,
(
SELECT
CONVERT(CHAR(10), fecha_recepcion, 103) AS fecha_recepcion
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.idEtapaTipoDocumento = red.idEtapaTipoDocumento
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS et ON et.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa
WHERE red.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento
AND red.recepcionado = 1
AND etd.habilitado = 1
AND et.nombre = 'Recepcion Autorizacion Contabilizacion'
AND et.habilitado = 1
)AS fecha_recepcion_Autorizacion,
(
SELECT
CONVERT(CHAR(10), fecha_autorizado, 103) AS fecha_autorizacion
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Autorizar_Documento] AS rad
WHERE rad.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento
AND rad.codigo_usuario = '{$codigo_usuario}'
AND ISNUll(rad.rechazado, 0) = 0
AND ISNULL(rad.autorizado, 0) = 1
AND rad.habilitado = 1
)AS fecha_autorizado_propia,
(
SELECT
CONVERT(CHAR(10), fecha_recepcion, 103) AS fecha_autorizacion
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.idEtapaTipoDocumento = red.idEtapaTipoDocumento
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS et ON et.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa
WHERE red.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento
AND red.recepcionado = 1
AND etd.habilitado = 1
AND et.nombre = 'Autorizacion'
AND et.habilitado = 1
)AS fecha_autorizado_documento,
(
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS existe_autorizacion_parcial
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Autorizar_Documento] AS rad
WHERE rad.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento
AND rad.codigo_usuario = '{$codigo_usuario}'
AND ISNUll(rad.rechazado, 0) = 0
AND ISNULL(rad.autorizado, 0) = 1
AND ISNULL(rad.autorizado_parcial, 0) = 1
AND rad.habilitado = 1
)AS existe_autorizacion_parcial,
(
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS existe_registro_peteroa
FROM [DynamicsAxPROD].[dbo].[VENDINVOICEJOUR]
WHERE (ORDERACCOUNT = f.rut_proveedor OR ORDERACCOUNT = '0'+f.rut_proveedor OR ORDERACCOUNT = SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, 0, LEN(f.rut_proveedor))+'-'+(SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, LEN(f.rut_proveedor), LEN(f.rut_proveedor)-1)))
AND LTRIM(INVOICEID) = f.numero_documento
)AS existe_registro_peteroa,
(
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS existe_registro_plomo
FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDINVOICEJOUR]
WHERE (ORDERACCOUNT = SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, 0, LEN(f.rut_proveedor))+'-'+(SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, LEN(f.rut_proveedor), LEN(f.rut_proveedor)-1)) OR ORDERACCOUNT = f.rut_proveedor)
AND LTRIM(INVOICEID) = f.numero_documento
)AS existe_registro_plomo
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS f
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Documento_Factura] AS df ON df.idFactura = f.idFactura
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd ON rd.idDocumento = f.idFactura
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td ON td.idTipoDocumento = rd.idTipoDocumento
WHERE ISNULL(rd.anulado, 0) = 0
{$condicion}
AND td.nombre = 'Factura'
AND td.habilitado = 1
AND (
EXISTS(
SELECT
*
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Autorizar_Documento] AS rad
WHERE rad.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento
AND rad.codigo_usuario = '{$codigo_usuario}'
AND ISNUll(rechazado, 0) = 0
AND ISNULL(autorizado, 0) = 1
AND rad.habilitado = 1
)
OR
EXISTS(
SELECT
*
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.idEtapaTipoDocumento = red.idEtapaTipoDocumento
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS et ON et.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa
WHERE red.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento
AND red.codigo_usuario = '{$codigo_usuario}'
AND red.recepcionado = 1
AND etd.habilitado = 1
AND et.nombre = 'Autorizacion'
AND et.habilitado = 1
)
)
ORDER BY f.fecha_recepcion ASC`
```

y este es el php:

```
public function buscar($codigo_usuario, $perfil, $estado_recepcion, $fecha_inicial_recepcion ="", $fecha_termino_recepcion ="", $numero_documento="", $tipo_dato="", $valor_dato="")
{
self::$metodo = 'buscar($codigo_usuario, $perfil, $estado_recepcion, $fecha_inicial_recepcion ="", $fecha_termino_recepcion ="", $numero_documento="", $tipo_dato="", $valor_dato="")';
$existe_factura_autorizable = false;
$indice_fila = 1;
$estado_estilo = true;
$condicion = '';
$condicion_fecha = '';
$condicion_fecha_parcial = '';
$condicion_fecha_final = '';
$sqlSistema = "SELECT
s.idSistema
FROM [Sistemas].[Sistema] AS s
INNER JOIN [Sistemas].[Usuario_Sistema] AS us ON us.idSistema = s.idSistema
WHERE us.codigo_usuario = '{$codigo_usuario}'
AND s.nombre = '".self::$sistema."'
AND (s.habilitado = 1 OR 1 IN(
SELECT
u.administrador
FROM [Sistemas].[Usuario] AS u
WHERE u.codigo_usuario = '{$codigo_usuario}'
)
)";
$rsSqlSistema = ConexionLn::consultar('Informatica', $sqlSistema, self::$modulo, self::$metodo);
if($rsSqlSistema != false)
{
// DATOS USUARIO AUTORIZADOR
$jerarquia_autorizador = Usuario::mostrarJerarquiaUsuario($codigo_usuario);
$dato = array('cargo');
$autorizador = Usuario::mostrarInformacion(0, $codigo_usuario, $dato);
if(!empty(trim($numero_documento)))
{
$condicion.= "AND f.numero_documento = '".utf8_decode(trim($numero_documento))."' ";
}
if(!empty(trim($tipo_dato)))
{
if(trim($tipo_dato) == 'nombre' && !empty(trim($valor_dato)))
{
$condicion.= "AND f.razon_social LIKE('%".utf8_decode(trim(str_replace("'", "''", $valor_dato)))."%')";
}
elseif(trim($tipo_dato) == 'rut' && !empty(trim($valor_dato)))
{
$condicion.= "AND f.rut_proveedor = '".utf8_decode(trim($valor_dato))."'";
}
}

if(trim($estado_recepcion) == 'pendiente')
{
}
elseif(trim($estado_recepcion) == 'autorizado')
{
$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida = explode('/', trim($fecha_inicial_recepcion));
if(!empty(trim($fecha_inicial_recepcion)) && !empty(trim($fecha_termino_recepcion)))
{
$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida = explode('/', trim($fecha_termino_recepcion));
$condicion_fecha_parcial.= "AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), rad.fecha_autorizado, 112) >= '$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[2]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[1]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[0]' 
AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), rad.fecha_autorizado, 112) <= '$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida[2]"."$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida[1]"."$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida[0] 23:59:59' ";
$condicion_fecha_final.= "AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), red.fecha_recepcion, 112) >= '$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[2]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[1]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[0]' 
AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), red.fecha_recepcion, 112) <= '$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida[2]"."$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida[1]"."$fecha_termino_recepcion_dividida[0] 23:59:59' ";
}
elseif(!empty(trim($fecha_inicial_recepcion)))
{
$condicion_fecha_parcial.= "AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), rad.fecha_autorizado, 112) = '$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[2]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[1]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[0]' ";
$condicion_fecha_final.= "AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), red.fecha_recepcion, 112) = '$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[2]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[1]"."$fecha_inicial_recepcion_dividida[0]' ";
}

$sqlFactura = <QUERY ARRIBA EXPUESTA>;

$rsSqlFactura = ConexionLn::consultar(self::$sistema, $sqlFactura, self::$modulo, self::$metodo);

if($rsSqlFactura != false)
{
$resultado="<form id='frmDocumentoAutorizacion' method='POST'>
<table id='tbDocumentoAutorizacion'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th align='left' style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Fecha<br />Recepcion<br />Autorizador</th>
<th align='left' style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Fecha<br />Autorizacion<br />Parcial</th>
<th align='left' style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Fecha<br />Autorizacion<br />Final</th>
<th>Numero<br />Factura</th>
<th align='left'>Fecha<br />Emision</th>
<th>Rut</th>
<th>Razon Social</th>
<th>Emitido A Empresa</th>
<th colspan='2'>Monto</th>
<th style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Distribucion Tercero<br />u<br />Orden Compra</th>
<th style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Es Autorizacion Parcial?</th>
<th style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Esta Contabilizado?</th>
<th style='font-size: 0.8em;'>Factura<br />Digital</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan='14'>
<input type='hidden' id='hdCantidadFactura' value='".count($rsSqlFactura)."'/>
</td>
</tr>";
foreach($rsSqlFactura AS $rowFactura)
{
$documento = "../../../documento/".self::$direccion_factura."/".str_replace("'", "&apos;", utf8_encode($rowFactura['nombre_digital']));
$monto_bruto = 0;
$orden_compra = '';
if($estado_estilo == true)
{

$estilo = "style='background: #FAFAFA;'";
$estado_estilo = false;
}
else
{
$estilo = "style='background: #FFFFFF;'";
$estado_estilo = true;
}
$resultado.= "<tr id='trFactura{$indice_fila}' {$estilo}>";
$resultado.= "<td align='center' style='width: 60px;'>{$rowFactura['fecha_recepcion_Autorizacion']}</td>";
$resultado.= "<td align='center' style='width: 60px;'>{$rowFactura['fecha_autorizado_propia']}</td>";
(!is_null($rowFactura['fecha_autorizado_documento'])) ? $resultado.= "<td style='width: 60px;' align='center'>{$rowFactura['fecha_autorizado_documento']}</td>" : $resultado.= "<td style='width: 60px;' align='center'>Pendiente</td>";
$resultado.= "<td align='right' style='width: 60px;'>
<label id='lblNumeroDocumento{$indice_fila}'>{$rowFactura['numero_documento']}</label>
</td>";
$resultado.= "<td align='center' style='width: 60px;'>{$rowFactura['fecha_emision']}</td>";
$resultado.= "<td align='right' style='width: 100px;'>".Usuario::cambiarFormatoRut('Dar', $rowFactura['rut_proveedor'])."</td>";
$resultado.= "<td style='width: 390px;'>".utf8_encode($rowFactura['razon_social'])."</td>";
$resultado.= "<td align='right' style='width: 200px;'>".utf8_encode($rowFactura['nombre_empresa'])."</td>";
(strpos($rowFactura['monto_bruto'], '.')) ? $monto_bruto = number_format($rowFactura['monto_bruto'], 2, ',', '.') : $monto_bruto = number_format($rowFactura['monto_bruto'], 0, ',', '.');
$resultado.= "<td align='right' style='width: 70px;'>{$monto_bruto}</td>";
$resultado.= "<td>{$rowFactura['indicador_moneda']}</td>";
$sqlOrdenCompra = "SELECT
foc.orden_compra
FROM Factura_Orden_Compra AS foc
WHERE foc.idFactura = {$rowFactura['idFactura']}";
$rsSqlOrdenCompra = ConexionLn::consultar(self::$sistema, $sqlOrdenCompra, self::$modulo, self::$metodo);
if($rsSqlOrdenCompra != false)
{
(count($rsSqlOrdenCompra) > 1) ? $orden_compra = $rsSqlOrdenCompra[0]['orden_compra']."..." : $orden_compra = $rsSqlOrdenCompra[0]['orden_compra'];
$resultado.= "<td align='right' style='width: 150px;'>
<input type='button' id='btnMostrarOrdenCompra' title='Mostrar Detalle Orden de Compra' value='{$orden_compra}' onclick='mostrarFacturaOrdenCompra({$indice_fila}, {$rowFactura['idFactura']})'/>
</td>";
}
else
{
$resultado.= "<td align='right' style='width: 150px;'>
<input type='button' id='btnMostrarDistribucion{$indice_fila}' class='btnMostrarDistribucion' {$estilo_mostrar_orden} title='Mostrar Detalle Distribucion' value='Distribucion' onclick='mostrarDistribucion({$indice_fila}, {$rowFactura['idFactura']})'/>
</td>";
}
$resultado.= "<td align='center'>";
```

y un poco mas de codigo que muestra...

Aca las imagenes:

1) imagen query usuario1 en sqlserver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.1) imagen query usuario1 en php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) imagen query usuario2 en sqlserver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.2) imagen query usuario2 en php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION 1**

imprimir con echo a usuario2(no trae datos en php): realice una impresión para ver si me estaba tomando los resultados de las variables "$codigo_usuario".

```
SELECT f.idFactura, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), f.fecha_recepcion, 103) AS fecha_recepcion, 
    f.numero_documento, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), f.fecha_emision, 103) AS fecha_emision, 
    f.rut_proveedor, 
    f.razon_social, 
    f.monto_bruto, 
    f.indicador_moneda, 
    f.valor_indicador, 
    df.idDocumentoFactura, 
    df.nombre AS nombre_digital, 
    rd.idRegistroDocumento, 
    ( SELECT em.nombre FROM [Informatica].[Sistemas].[Empresa] AS em WHERE em.codigo = f.codigo_empresa AND em.habilitado = 1 )AS nombre_empresa, 
    ( SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), fecha_recepcion, 103) AS fecha_recepcion 
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red 
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.idEtapaTipoDocumento = red.idEtapaTipoDocumento 
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS et ON et.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa 
WHERE red.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento 
AND red.recepcionado = 1 
AND etd.habilitado = 1 
AND et.nombre = 'Recepcion Autorizacion Contabilizacion' 
AND et.habilitado = 1 )AS fecha_recepcion_Autorizacion, 
    ( SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), fecha_autorizado, 103) AS fecha_autorizacion 
    FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Autorizar_Documento] AS rad 
    WHERE rad.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento 
    AND rad.codigo_usuario = 'CE011' 
    AND ISNUll(rad.rechazado, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(rad.autorizado, 0) = 1 
    AND rad.habilitado = 1 )AS fecha_autorizado_propia,
    ( SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), fecha_recepcion, 103) AS fecha_autorizacion 
    FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.idEtapaTipoDocumento = red.idEtapaTipoDocumento 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS et ON et.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa 
    WHERE red.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento 
    AND red.recepcionado = 1 
    AND etd.habilitado = 1 
    AND et.nombre = 'Autorizacion' 
    AND et.habilitado = 1 )AS fecha_autorizado_documento, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS existe_autorizacion_parcial 
    FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Autorizar_Documento] AS rad 
    WHERE rad.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento 
    AND rad.codigo_usuario = 'CE011' AND ISNUll(rad.rechazado, 0) = 0 
    AND ISNULL(rad.autorizado, 0) = 1 AND ISNULL(rad.autorizado_parcial, 0) = 1 
    AND rad.habilitado = 1 )AS existe_autorizacion_parcial, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS existe_registro_peteroa 
    FROM [DynamicsAxPROD].[dbo].[VENDINVOICEJOUR] 
    WHERE (ORDERACCOUNT = f.rut_proveedor OR ORDERACCOUNT = '0'+f.rut_proveedor OR ORDERACCOUNT = SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, 0, LEN(f.rut_proveedor))+'-'+(SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, LEN(f.rut_proveedor), LEN(f.rut_proveedor)-1))) AND LTRIM(INVOICEID) = f.numero_documento )AS existe_registro_peteroa, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS existe_registro_plomo 
    FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDINVOICEJOUR] WHERE (ORDERACCOUNT = SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, 0, LEN(f.rut_proveedor))+'-'+(SUBSTRING(f.rut_proveedor, LEN(f.rut_proveedor), LEN(f.rut_proveedor)-1)) OR ORDERACCOUNT = f.rut_proveedor) AND LTRIM(INVOICEID) = f.numero_documento )AS existe_registro_plomo 
    FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS f 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Documento_Factura] AS df ON df.idFactura = f.idFactura 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd ON rd.idDocumento = f.idFactura 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td ON td.idTipoDocumento = rd.idTipoDocumento 
    WHERE ISNULL(rd.anulado, 0) = 0 
    AND td.nombre = 'Factura' 
    AND td.habilitado = 1 
    AND ( EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Autorizar_Documento] AS rad 
    WHERE rad.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento 
    AND rad.codigo_usuario = 'CE011' 
    AND ISNUll(rechazado, 0) = 0 
    AND ISNULL(autorizado, 0) = 1 
    AND rad.habilitado = 1 ) 
    OR EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.idEtapaTipoDocumento = red.idEtapaTipoDocumento 
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS et ON et.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa 
    WHERE red.idRegistroDocumento = rd.idRegistroDocumento 
    AND red.codigo_usuario = 'CE011' 
    AND red.recepcionado = 1 
    AND etd.habilitado = 1 
    AND et.nombre = 'Autorizacion' 
    AND et.habilitado = 1 ) ) 
    ORDER BY f.fecha_recepcion ASC`
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68667/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-francisco-acevedo).

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68669/discussion-on-question-by-francisco-acevedo-query-no-obtienes-datos-a-traves-de).